# How to fix an error printing a deck of cards in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I'm on an assignment to create a deck of card and print in out in many ways. But I'm having an issue where the result is 52 cards x 4 times. Probably some issue over declaring my card obj with my suit array but I don't know how to fix it. Can anyone help?

So basically I made a Card class which contains value of the card/or rank, suit, and face(what printed show on card). Then a Deck class which create an array of 52 cards, and add a shuffle method as well. Goal is to print cards before and after shuffle.

The problem is in Deck class, which my loop for its constructor seems quite odd that it prints out x4 the result. I've tried moved some but doesn't work.

```
public Deck() {
    for (int i = 0; i<c.length;i++) {
        for (int j =0; j<suit.length;j++) {
            for (int k =0; k<face.length;k++) {
                s = suit[j];
                f = face[k];
                switch(f) {
                    case "2": v=2; break;
                    case "3": v=3; break;
                    case "4": v=4; break;
                    case "5": v=5; break;
                    case "6": v=6; break;
                    case "7": v=7; break;
                    case "8": v=8; break;
                    case "9": v=9; break;
                    case "10": v=10; break;
                    case "Queen": v=11; break;
                    case "Jack": v=11; break;
                    case "King": v=11; break;
                    case "Ace": v=12; break;
                }
                c[i] = new Card(v,s,f);
                System.out.println(c[i].toString());
            }
        }
    }            
}
```

Expected result: 52 cards displayed before and after shuffle

Comment: You should add the relevant language tag to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are instantiating a new `Card` instance `face.length * suit.length * c.length` times. Why are you iterating over the `c` array? If you want to create one of each card and store those in `c`, then do something like this:

```
int i = 0;
for (var suit : suits)
    for (var face : faces)
        c[i++] = new Card(suit, face);
```

Comment: Oh, I forgot to copy that as well, c is the array instance of the Card class - or a deck, length is 52 for 52 cards

Comment: Okay, but there is no reason to iterate over that array if you are trying to create 52  card instances.

Answer (score -1):

Every thing is fine, its just that your are `initializing new card` at the wrong place.

**Like this:**

```
public Deck() {
    for (int i = 0; i<c.length;i++) {
        for (int j =0; j<suit.length;j++) {
            for (int k =0; k<face.length;k++) {
                s = suit[j];
                f = face[k];
                switch(f) {
                    case "2": v=2; break;
                    case "3": v=3; break;
                    case "4": v=4; break;
                    case "5": v=5; break;
                    case "6": v=6; break;
                    case "7": v=7; break;
                    case "8": v=8; break;
                    case "9": v=9; break;
                    case "10": v=10; break;
                    case "Queen": v=11; break;
                    case "Jack": v=11; break;
                    case "King": v=11; break;
                    case "Ace": v=12; break;
                }
            }
        }
        c[i] = new Card(Integer.pareInt(s),s,f);
        System.out.println(c[i].toString());
    }            
}
```

Comment: Dear down voter, whats wrong in my solution ? So that i can fix it.

Comment: Hi, I forgot to copy the upper part of it, thought those lines are enough lol, i already declared the variable v so parseInt is not the one(i tried tho and ye not work). Again my output show 52 cards but some how x4 them, maybe the suit one but Idk how I can order it right.